# How to do sum of a sum in access report?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have one textbox as

```
    =[Price]*[Quantity]
```

and another as

```
    =Sum([Price]*[Quantity])
```

i need a third as

```
    =Sum(Sum([Price]*[Quantity]))
```

But i cant do the third as I cant do a sum of a sum, how can i work around this?

Comment: are these each at different grouping levels?

Comment: Not entirely sure what that means im stupid, the first is in 'detail', the second is 'orderID footer' and the third is in 'page footer' so i assume so

Comment: If you have a  'orderID footer' , this means that you added a report group and those can be nested, i.e. have different levels.

Comment: How would i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that. Create nested group headers and footers and place the text boxes in the group headers or footers. Regardless of the nesting level, you can always use

```
=Sum([Price]*[Quantity])
```

as control source of the text box. Access knows what to sum up. The same works for the page footer as well.

Note that you don't have to make a sum of sums because

```
sum( sum(a, b, c), sum(d, e), sum(f, g, h, i) ) = sum(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)
```

i.e., the sum in a higher level group or in the report footer does not make a sum of sums, instead, it makes a sum of all involved items of all lower level groups.

Comment: But i already have one as =Sum([Price]*[Quantity]) i need another thats the sum of that

Comment: If you have `=Sum([Price]*[Quantity])` on the report footer, it will automatically sum up the whole report. There is no need to make the sum of the sum because it is not any different from the simple sum of the whole.